# add new and update existing document in embedded array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to add or remove documents from an embedded array, and update existing documents
in an embedded array?

e.g.  Given

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("547dd21f6e04d152fccedf1b"),
    "intF" : 0,
    "arrayD" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "baz",
            "contents" : "baz contents"
        }
}
```

trying

```
db.dummy.update(
    // query 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("547dd21f6e04d152fccedf1b")
    },

    // update 
    {
         $set : { "arrayD.0.contents": "no contents" },
         $push : { arrayD : { $each : [ { name : "bam", contents : null } ] }
                 }
    },

    // options 
    {
        "multi" : false,  // update only one document 
        "upsert" : false  // insert a new document, if no existing document match the query 
    }
);
```

gives error

Cannot update 'arrayD.0.contents' and 'arrayD' at the same time

The options I see are

1. Use $set and write whole array
2. Use multiple updates, one for $set to modify existing entries, one for $push/$pull to add/remove entries.

is there a better way?

Comment: it's because you write $push and $set at the same time write only one or another !!!

Comment: Even a find and modify also doesn't yeild                                           db.test.findAndModify({
    query: { "_id": ObjectId("547e1510502b7babde6a60da") },
    update: {  $set : { "arrayD[0].contents": "no contents" },
 $push : { arrayD : { $each : [ { name : "bam", contents : null } ] } }
 }, upsert: true
});

Comment: There are a number of JIRA tickets related to this sort of issue. For example: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6566

Comment: This is the exact JIRA ticket for this issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10711

Comment: Thanks Will - now I can watch those JIRAs